# Erro na criação da chave estrangeira fk_cliente no banco de dados

Tags: java

Olá,quando eu estava fazendo o relacionamento da tabela cliente com a tabela vendas, na hora de finalizar, o sistema exibiu uma  mensagem de erro, por isso o relacionamento não foi criado a mensagem é esta: Erro criando chave estrangeira em fk_id_cliente(verifique tipo de dados), o que entendo é que o erro está nos tipos de dados, eu alterei,porém continua o erro não criando o relacionamento, as tabelas do banco de dados estão logo abaixo e depois os campos da chave primaria tabela vendas e chave estrangeira fk_cliente e também o campo da chave primaria tabela cliente Quais os dados que devem ser alterado nas tabelas?   por genteleza responder.

tabela cliente

NOME           TIPO  tamanho/valores Predefinido   agrupamento  Atributos Nulo AI
pk_id_cliente  int   11                nenhum
Nome  Tipo     tamanho\valores Predefinido Agrupamento     Atributos Nulo AI
Nome  VARCHAR  300             nenhum      utf8_general_ci
Nome      tipo     tamanho\valores Predefinido Agrupamento     Atributos Nulo AI
endereco  VARCHAR  300             nenhum      utf8_general_ci Atributos Nulo AI
Nome      tipo     tamanho\valores Predefinido Agrupamento     Atributos Nulo AI
bairro    Varchar  300             nenhum      utf8_general_ci
Nome      tipo     tamanho\valores Predefinido Agrupamento     Atributos Nulo AI
cidade    VARCHAR  200             nenhum      utf8_general_ci
Nome      tipo     tamanho\valores Predefinido Agrupamento     Atributos Nulo AI
uf        VARCHAR   2              nenhum      utf8_general_ci
Nome      tipo     tamanho\valores Predefinido Agrupamento     Atributos Nulo AI
cep       VARCHAR  9               nenhum      utf8_general_ci
Nome      tipo     tamanho\valores Predefinido Agrupamento     Atributos Nulo AI
telefone  VARCHAR  15              nenhum      utf8_general_ci

TABELA VENDAS

Nome         tipo   tanho/valores  Predefinido Agrupamento     Atributos Nulo AI
pk_id_vendas int    11             nenhum                                     v
Nome          tipo   tanho/valores  Predefinido Agrupamento     Atributos Nulo AI
fk_id_cliente int    11              nenhum                     UNSIGNED
Nome           tipo   tanho/valores  Predefinido Agrupamento   Atributos  Nulo AI
VEN_DATA_VENDA DATE                  nenhum
Nome              tipo   tanho/valores  Predefinido Agrupamento Atributos Nulo AI
ven_valor_liquido DOUBLE                nenhum
Nome              tipo   tanho/valores  Predefinido Agrupamento Atributos Nulo AI
ven_valor_bruto   DOUBLE                nenhum
Nome              tipo   tanho/valores  Predefinido Agrupamento Atributos Nulo AI
ven_desconto      DOUBLE                nenhum

CAMPO DA CHAVE PRIMARIA TABELA VENDAS

nome          tipo    tamanho/valores   predefinido Agrupamento Atributos nulo AI
pk_id_vendas  int     11                nenhum                                 v

CAMPO DA CHAVE ESTRANGEIRA FK_CLIENTE

nome            tipo   tamanho/valores  predefinido Agrupamento Atributos nulo AI
fk_id_cliente   int     11               nenhum                 UNSIGNED

CAMPO CHAVE PRIMARIA TABELA CLIENTE

nome          Tipo  tamanho/valores   predefinido Agrupamento Atributos nulo AI
pk_id_cliente int    11               nenhum                                 v

Comment: ola bem vindo Antonio. Dê uma olhada na sua pergunta e tente formatar, veja que tem muita informação mas está ilegível, difícil te ajudar :(  [clique aqui para editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/494869/edit) e tente melhorar

Comment: Sua chave estrangeira, aparentemente `fk_id_cliente` da tabela vendas, está com o atributo UNSIGNED. Tudo indica que ela referencia o campo `pk_id_cliente` da tabela cliente que não tem tal atributo.

Comment: valeu,irmão,pela correção conseguir fazer o relacionamento.